# Many-to-Many Relationship Query

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I'm trying to query a table that holds the id of two tables that holds the id to two other tables (where one of these holds the id to other tables)

Hell, I know.

As I am a beginner in SQL, how do I go about efficiently querying this to get all the details of each table? As of now i only see a very long set of Select statements. Here is how the tables are set up below

[image: EER Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking.
If you need a SELECT command it would have 2 INNER joins. But, if you are asking to get all the info (and children) then it would need more INNER joins. OR if you are using a persistent client for your application.... I just don't know. Because it is incomplete data to do it.

Comment: What I want is basically all the data you see there excluding the IDs. I was wondering if there were any keywords or efficient way dive in and do so than a lot of joins.

Comment: You need to inform the SQL engine how your DB design relate to each table. So you need every JOIN. You can also create VIEWs, if your DB engine supports it, but you still need to define the relationships.